# WordPress API have a colour picker widget?

Tags: wordpress

Does the WordPress API have a colour picker widget? I'm trying to add a colour picker to my WordPress plugin and deciding between using a 3rd party colour picker library or using something in WP API.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find all core scripts used by wordpress, colorpicker being one of them: 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/#core-registered-scripts